# How do i enhance rails gem to serve endpoints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-engines

I'm new to rails, I am reading through the documentation and trying to figure-out how can i enhance existing `gem` so i can add few end points which can be consumed from the client applications (angular apps, vue apps, react apps).

Example:

1. I have existing gem called `book_scheduler`. looking at this it doesn't have `app` or `config` folder structure but `bin` and `lib`.
2. Now i would like to enhance the gem to have two endpoints, so the clients can call `book/count` and `book/return` using `fetch`.

How can i accomplish this ? Can i somehow enhance the gem to have rails engine and define routes ? Any advice or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes an engine is the best way to handle this in a gem, expose something that can be mounted and then take it from there.  The devise source code is pretty exceptional as an example.  Also https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Comment: what about cloning existing gem and check few tutorials about a building a gem in ruby and then enhance that gem for your needs?

Comment: @Austio and @Nezir thanks, so the gem will/has to get converted to an engine. An engine cannot be part of the existing gem ?If we do convert the existing gem then will it need to be re written from catch as `rails plugin new blorgh --mountable` is to create new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan to use `book_scheduler` in many rails application, you can make it an `Engine`
It will help you to cerate many rails application with the same endpoints

But if you want to build a single rails API (used by multiple client apps), you should do the following :

- include your gem in your project with bundler
- define your endoints in routes.rb
- create a controller that implement the endoints based on existing gem
- create your views if needed. Or simply render in JSON